# How can I "extend" an SQLite database?

Tags: android, database

I'm building an Android application which collects all the contact information from the device (via SQLite, I believe). Unfortunately I need some additional informations from the Internet I want to store in the mentioned database to be able to query the things (provided by me) the next time the user opens my app, so he can use it even without network connection. 
I use content providers for getting contact details.

What is the most efficient and relatively simple way to get this done?

Comment: get all contacts from the device and save it in your app's database along with modified values

Comment: That would mean I have to get the content of my database then the default database. Update mine if there are differences and after shutdown, save them all. Wouldn't that be slow?

Comment: no at start of your app get all contacts and save it in your app's database. Don't query phone's database everytime and do changes in your app's database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is to create your own content provider - using SQLite as your storage technology. You need to create a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` - providing implementation for the `onCreate(Database database)` and there you specify the SQL query to create the table as you desire it. For example:

```
public class YourDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "yourDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public YourDBHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        //here you write the code to create the table as you desire:
        String query = "CREATE TABLE MoreContactInfo <your columns def>...";
        database.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //do the upgrade (e.g drop and create table)
    }
}
```

Now to implement the content provider, you extend the `ContentProvider` class:
`public class YourContentProvider extends ContentProvider`.
And in the onCreate callback of `YourContentProvider` class you instantiate your SQLite-helper (ie.`YourDBHelper`) : See the example below:

```
...
  private YourDBHelper yourDatabase = null;
   @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        yourDatabase = new YourDBHelper(getContext());     
        return false;
    }
```

To insert data, you override the insert method like this:

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    //ideally you use URI-Matcher to figure out who to treat the insert     
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = yourDatabase.getWritableDatabase();

    long id = sqlDB.insert("<your-table-name-here>", null, values);     
    return Uri.parse("<your-content-provider-base-uri"> +"/"+id);

}
```

I know this might seem like a lot of work, but I think this is what you need to do in order to have your own content provider to allow you to save and retrieve data in a standard way within your Android app.
I have a code walk-through presentation [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1snCr1LIUWJOXJiT3VpNlFFOVE/view) if you are interested.

Comment: This seems like the good answer. I will also take a look at your presentation. Thank you. :)